# Remove everything inside <> characters in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a massive column value that will have multiple html code, example:

```
</></>some wording</></></>some other stuff</></>
```

I want to query this but only search inside the "some wording" or "some other stuff" (Ignoring everything that is inside the brackets</>).

Any Idea how can I do this in MySql?

Comment: REGEXP_REPLACE()

Comment: Would you have an example of how to use it?

Comment: I found this:

CREATE TABLE _audit
    (`aud_desc` longtext)
;
    
INSERT INTO _audit
    (`aud_desc`)
VALUES
    ('3242343<div><span style="font-size: large;">Regression Environment:<4324234><24234234>dfdf'),
    ('<img> word'),
    ('word <img>')
;
    SELECT *
    FROM _audit where REPLACE(aud_desc, SUBSTRING(aud_desc, LOCATE('<', aud_desc), LOCATE('>', aud_desc)), '') 
    like '%4324234%' 
The Problem is that is returning the record even when 4324234 is inside the brackets... I only want to return the row if the search match 3242343, Regression Environment: or  dfdf

Comment: Then don't do the REPLACE() at all. Just use `WHERE aud_desc LIKE '%4324234%'`

Comment: Doing just a Like "%word%" will also search inside the brackets <some html code> which will return false positive records, I only want to do the search for everything that is Outside the brackets.

Comment: In the example search you show, the value 4324234 is not only inside html tags, but it is also inside angled brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using the suggested [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) in the first Comment:

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE('the massive html code with bunch of tags','<.+?\>', '')
```